# Fast Update from Spark Mysql

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I have a table with 4 millions records and new data come on daily basis and I need to update table after processing new data. Currently I am doing this for this purpose. I am using scala.

```
val batchSize = 1000
df.rdd mapPartitions (_ grouped batchSize) foreach { batch =>
  {
    val connection = getConnection();
    val statement = connection.createStatement();
    batch.foreach { row =>
      val query = "UPDATE temp SET file_name='" + row.get(0) + " WHERE id=" + row.get(3);
      statement.executeUpdate(query);

    }
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

This is not the exact query but i am doing like this. This is taking about 1 hour to update the table. I need to improve performance. How can i achieve performance.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the SQL database is not indexed, add indexes according to the row.get(3) field.
2. If the SQL database is not innoDB, make it innoDB - innoDB is better for concurrent operations (needed for the concurrency)

It looks like the concurrent part with spark is made correctly and further optimizations should be made from the infrastructure (database in this case)

Comment: yes I am using innoDB  and also have index on key but maximum updates per second is 6000 to 7000 and on table with 4million rows it is taking round about 11 minutes.

Comment: @AtifShahzad you can try to further parallelize `batch`, what data type is it? you can use the `par` keyword like this: `(1 to 10000).toArray.par`

Comment: batch datatype is Seq[Row]